# Google Sheets copy function

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I made this function that I include in this post hereunder to copy particular cells from New Inv Entry sheet to Invoices sheet when I click on Save button that I made in New Inv Entry. I already entered data in Invoices sheet manually but the problem is when I try to enter a new entry via New Inv Entry the function pastes only one cell in Invoices from New Inv Entry and didn't pastes in last row, just replace other entry.

I appreciate if someone help me to configure the problem.

Thank you

```
function copy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('New Inv Entry');
  var Properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var lastrow = Properties.getProperty('lastrow');
  if(lastrow==null) lastrow=1;
  else lastrow = parseInt(lastrow);
  Properties.setProperty('lastrow',(lastrow+1));
  var v = s1.getRange('C3:G11').getValue();
  ss.getSheetByName('Invoices').getRange('A:E' + lastrow).setValue(v);
};
```

Comment: Can you describe better what is the issue you are facing? If you need to get the row after the last row with data, why not using [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) and then +1?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

`Properties.setProperty('lastrow',(lastrow+1));`

just simply

`lastrow = lastrow+1;`

since you don't really want to change the property as stored in the `PropertiesService`, but your local variable called `lastrow`.

I'd assume `getValue()` and `setValue()` only works for single cells. You should use [`copyTo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) instead:

`s1.getRange('C3:G11').copyTo(ss.getSheetByName('Invoices').getRange('A' + lastrow))`

(Note that `:E` part is not needed for the destination range, because `copyTo` knows anyway the size of the range being copied.)

Answer (score 0):

Sbnc.eu thank you for your reply. You gave me lots of help with your answer, it saves all the cells. I wish that particular cells only save in Invoices. I tried to amend this one hereunder but without success.

```
s1.getRange('C3', 'C5', 'C7', 'C9', 'C11:G11').copyTo(ss.getSheetByName('Invoices').getRange('A' + lastrow))
```

Apart from that I already have about 2.5k entries already inserted in Invoices sheet but when I hit the save button to execute that function with your amendments you gave, the new entry replace an entry that already inserted.

Comment: I think if you have another question you should post that as another topic on stackoverflow.com, otherwise the question-answer pattern is broken.
Being said that, if you wish to copy more than one separate ranges, you should copy them one-by-one, so a separate copy command for `C3`, another for `C5` etc.